# Select query for collating rows as a columns

Tags: sql

I'm not the best at SQL, so I'm asking for some help after trying to find a solution for a while.

I have a table where I store options related to accounts:

```
id, accountid, option_name, option_value
```

Can I write a query to collate all rows as columns?

Currently I'm having to do them manually as follows:

```
(SELECT option_value from account_options WHERE accountid=a.id and option_name = 
'phonenumber') as phonenumber,
(SELECT option_value from account_options WHERE accountid=a.id and option_name = 'nickname') 
as nickname,
(SELECT option_value from account_options WHERE accountid=a.id and option_name = 
 'profileicon') as profileicon
```

and so on. Is it possible to write a query where the option_name becomes the name of the column and I can fetch all option_values in one simple query?

Please bear with me. SQL isn't my forte.

Comment: Please, provide sample data and expected output. What database?

Comment: You need to redesign your database if possible.  Use a proper, normalised structure with a column for each value. Or check out `PIVOT` depending on your DB.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. I think I'm happy with the current database design. I guess I'm going to have to write long SQL queries in order to handle the design, but it suits my style of coding and keeps the tables from having unnecessary columns. Thanks again for all who took the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN option_name = 'phonenumber' THEN option_value END) as phonenumber,
       MAX(CASE WHEN option_name = 'nickname' THEN option_value END) as nickname,
       . . . 
FROM account_options
GROUP BY accountid;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But i've currently got 20 odd option_names. These will increase in time. Isn't there a way where I can run a query to fetch all rows and convert them to columns instead?

Comment: @user2672052 . . . (1) This answers the question that you asked here.  (2) This is easily extensible to more columns, which is what the `. . .` is intended to illustrate.  (3) You can construct the query using a spreadsheet or dynamic SQL if you don't want to type it all out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have to use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE(ID int, option_name varchar(30), option_value varchar(30))
INSERT INTO @SampleData (ID, option_name, option_value)
VALUES(1, 'nickname', 'Adam'),
(1, 'profileicon', 'profile1.jpg'),
(1, 'phonenumber', '123456789'),
(2, 'nickname', 'Eve'),
(2, 'profileicon', 'profile2.jpg'),
(2, 'phonenumber', '987654321'),
(3, 'nickname', 'Adam'),
(3, 'profileicon', 'profile3.jpg'),
(3, 'phonenumber', '741258963')

SELECT ID, [nickname], [profileicon], [phonenumber]
FROM (
    SELECT ID, option_name, option_value
    FROM  @SampleData
) dt
PIVOT(MAX(option_value) FOR option_name IN ([nickname], [profileicon], [phonenumber])) pvt
```

Result:

```
ID  nickname    profileicon phonenumber
1   Adam    profile1.jpg    123456789
2   Eve profile2.jpg    987654321
3   Adam    profile3.jpg    741258963
```

For dynamic version, please see:
[SQLShack - Dynamic Pivot Tables in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/)
[essentialsql.com - What is a Dynamic Pivot Table?](https://www.essentialsql.com/create-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-server/)
You'll find more on Google.